# NOt optimized code,how can i fix it?

Tags: python

I dont now how to optimize me code. The game i created lags 15 fps, how i can it be reduced and optimize.This my code, I try to do optimize, but i cant. Please 
help:

```py
    import pygame
    from random import randint
    import time
    import os 

    pygame.init()

    name = os.getlogin()
    path = r'C:\\Users\\' + name + r'\\Desktop\\WHITE\\'

    imhero = path + r'hero.png'
    imfloor = path + r'floor.png'

    imeasybutton = path + r'easy_button.png'
    imnormbutton = path + r'normal_button.png'
    imhardbutton = path + r'hard_button.png'
    imheart = path + r'heart.png'
    imstart = path + r'start_button.png'
    imbackground = path + r'background.png'
    imbonus_1 = path + r'heart_bonus.png'
    imbackground_start = path + r'background_start.png'
    picture = [path + "object_1.png", path + "object_2.png",path + "object_3.png",path + "object_4.png"]
    point = 0
    life_count = 0
    y_start = 375

    SCREEN = (600, 500)
    x = randint(1,500)
    BLACK = (0,0,0)
    WHITE = (255,255,255)
    BLUE = (0,255, 220)
    Salmon = (255, 160, 122)

    speed = 0

    FPS = 30

    motion = "STOP"
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    sc = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
    y = y_start

    y_object_1 = 0
    y_heart_1 = y_object_1

    start = True
    choise = False
    easy = False
    normal = False
    hard = False

    button = pygame.Surface((300,100))
    sc.blit(button,(50,50))
    difficlt = ""

    background = pygame.sprite.Group()
    hearts = pygame.sprite.Group()
    object_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
    hero_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

    game_over_text = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 36).render("GAME OVER", 1, (255, 0, 0))
    game_over_rect = game_over_text.get_rect(center=(SCREEN[0]//2, SCREEN[1]//2))

    class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self,filename,group):

                pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                self.image = pygame.image.load(filename)
                self.rect= self.image.get_rect(center = (SCREEN[0]//2,SCREEN[0]//2))
                self.add(group) 

    class Object(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

        class box(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
            def __init__(self,filename,group,y_object_1):

                pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
                self.image.set_colorkey((255,255,255))
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (randint(1,SCREEN[0]), y_object_1))
                self.add(group) 

            def update(self, *args):

                if y_object_1 < SCREEN[1]:
                    self.rect[1]+=speed
                    time.sleep(0.001)


        class floor (pygame.sprite.Sprite):

            def __init__(self,filename,group,x_floor,y_floor):
                pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x_floor, y_floor))
                self.add(group) 

    class Hero(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

        def __init__(self,filename,group,x,y):
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
            self.rect =  self.image.get_rect(center =(x,y))
            self.add(group) 

        def update_hero(self, move):

            if move == "LEFT":
                self.rect[0] -= 30

            elif move == "RIGHT":
                self.rect[0] += 30

            if self.rect[0] > SCREEN[0]:
                self.rect[0]= 10

            if self.rect[0] <10:
                self.rect[0]= 590

    class Heart(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

        def __init__(self,filename,group,x,y):

            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
            self.rect =  self.image.get_rect(center =(x,y))
            self.add(group)


    class Buttons(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

        def __init__(self,filename,group,x,y):

            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
            self.rect =  self.image.get_rect(center=(x,y))
            self.add(group)

        def pressed(self, mouse):
            if mouse[0] > self.rect.topleft[0]:
                if mouse[1] > self.rect.topleft[1]:
                    if mouse[0] < self.rect.bottomright[0]:
                        if mouse[1] < self.rect.bottomright[1]:
                            return True
                        else: return False
                    else: return False
                else: return False
            else: return False

    class bonus(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        class Heart_Bonus(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

            def __init__(self,filename,group,y_heart_1):

                pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
                self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
                self.image.set_colorkey((255,255,255))
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (randint(1,SCREEN[0]), y_heart_1))
                self.add(group) 

            def update(self, *args):

                if y_heart_1 < SCREEN[1]:
                    self.rect[1]+=speed
                    time.sleep(0.001)
    def update():
        object_group.update()
        bonus_group.update()
        background.draw(sc)
        hero_group.draw(sc)
        object_group.draw(sc)
        hearts.draw(sc)
        bonus_group.draw(sc)
    buttons = pygame.sprite.Group()
    start = pygame.sprite.Group()
    bonus_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

    fon_start = Background(imbackground_start,start)

    start_button = Buttons(imstart,start,SCREEN[0]//2, SCREEN[1]//2)

    while start:

        start.draw(sc)

        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               start = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

                if start_button.pressed(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) == True :
                    start_button.kill()
                    choise = True
                    start = False

    while choise:

        easy_button = Buttons(imeasybutton,buttons,300,150)
        normal_button = Buttons(imnormbutton,buttons,300,300)
        hard_button = Buttons(imhardbutton,buttons,300,450)

        sc.fill(Salmon)
        buttons.draw(sc)

        choise_text = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 30).render("ВЫБЕРИТЕ УРОВЕНЬ СЛОЖНОСТИ" , 1, (BLACK))
        сhoise_rect = choise_text.get_rect(center=(SCREEN[0]//2,50))
        sc.blit(choise_text,сhoise_rect)
        pygame.display.update()

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               choise = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if easy_button.pressed(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) == True :

                    difficlt = "easy"
                    life_count = 3
                    choise = False
                    break

                if normal_button.pressed(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) == True :
                    difficlt = "normal"
                    life_count = 2
                    choise = False
                    break

                if hard_button.pressed(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) == True :
                    difficlt = "hard"
                    life_count = 1
                    choise = False
                    break

    if difficlt == "easy":

        speed = 15

        easy_button.kill()
        normal_button.kill()
        hard_button.kill()

        easy = True
        normal = False
        hard = False

        object1 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
        object2 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
        object3 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
        object4 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
        object5 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)

        heart1 = Heart(imheart,hearts,50,450)
        heart2 = Heart(imheart,hearts,100,450)
        heart3 = Heart(imheart,hearts,150,450)

    if difficlt == "normal":
        speed = 20
        easy_button.kill()
        normal_button.kill()
        hard_button.kill()

        easy = False
        normal = True
        hard = False

        object1 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
        object2 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
        object3 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
        object4 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
        object5 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
        object6 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)

        heart1 = Heart(imheart,hearts,50,450)
        heart2 = Heart(imheart,hearts,100,450)

    if difficlt == "hard":

        speed = 25

        easy_button.kill()
        normal_button.kill()
        hard_button.kill()

        easy = False
        normal = False
        hard = True

        object1 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
        object2 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
        object3 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
        object4 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
        object5 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
        object6 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
        object7 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)

        heart1 = Heart(imheart,hearts,50,450)

    floor = Object.floor(imfloor,background,300,450)

    hero = Hero(imhero,hero_group,x,y)

    fon = Background(imbackground,background)


    while easy:

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                easy = False

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and hero.rect[0]  < SCREEN[0]:

            hero.update_hero('RIGHT')

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and hero.rect[0] > 0:

            hero.update_hero('LEFT')


        update()

        pygame.display.update()

        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(floor,object_group):

            object1.kill()
            object2.kill()
            object3.kill()
            object4.kill()
            object5.kill()

            object1 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
            object2 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
            object3 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
            object4 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
            object5 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)

            point+=1

        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(hero,object_group):

            life_count-=1

            if life_count == 2 :

                heart3.kill()

                object1.kill()
                object2.kill()
                object3.kill()
                object4.kill()
                object5.kill()

                object1 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
                object2 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
                object3 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
                object4 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
                object5 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)

            if life_count == 1 :

                heart2.kill()

                object1.kill()
                object2.kill()
                object3.kill()
                object4.kill()
                object5.kill()

                object1 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
                object2 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
                object3 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
                object4 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
                object5 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)

            if life_count == 0:

                sc.fill(BLUE)
                heart1.kill()

                game_over_text = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 36).render("GAME OVER" , 1, (255, 0, 0))
                game_over_text2 = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 36).render( "SCORE: " + str(point) , 1, (255, 0, 0))

                game_over_rect = game_over_text.get_rect(center=(SCREEN[0]//2, SCREEN[1]//2))
                game_over_rect2 = game_over_text.get_rect(center=(SCREEN[0]//2, (SCREEN[1]//2)+50))

                sc.blit(game_over_text,game_over_rect)
                sc.blit(game_over_text2,game_over_rect2)
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(5)

                break

        point_text = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 36).render("SCORE" + str(point), 1, (255, 0, 0))
        point_rect = point_text.get_rect(center=(450,450))
        sc.blit(point_text, point_rect)
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.Clock().tick(FPS)




    while normal:

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                normal = False

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and hero.rect[0]  < SCREEN[0]:

            hero.update_hero('RIGHT')

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and hero.rect[0] > 0:

            hero.update_hero('LEFT')

        update()
        pygame.display.update()
        p = randint(1,10)   

        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(floor,object_group):


            object1.kill()
            object2.kill()
            object3.kill()
            object4.kill()
            object5.kill()
            object6.kill()

            object1 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
            object2 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
            object3 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
            object4 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
            object5 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)

            if p%2 == 0:

                object6 =  bonus.Heart_Bonus(imbonus_1, bonus_group,y_heart_1)

            point+=1

        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(hero,bonus_group):

            if  life_count ==1:
                life_count+=1
                heart2 = Heart(imheart,hearts,100,450)
                object6.kill()

        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(hero,object_group):

            life_count-=1

            if life_count == 1 :

                heart2.kill()

                object1.kill()
                object2.kill()
                object3.kill()
                object4.kill()
                object5.kill()
                object6.kill()

                object1 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
                object2 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
                object3 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
                object4 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
                object5 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
                object6 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)

            if life_count == 0:

                sc.fill(BLUE)
                heart1.kill()

                game_over_text = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 36).render("GAME OVER" , 1, (255, 0, 0))
                game_over_text2 = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 36).render( "SCORE: " + str(point) , 1, (255, 0, 0))

                game_over_rect = game_over_text.get_rect(center=(SCREEN[0]//2, SCREEN[1]//2))
                game_over_rect2 = game_over_text.get_rect(center=(SCREEN[0]//2, (SCREEN[1]//2)+50))

                sc.blit(game_over_text,game_over_rect)
                sc.blit(game_over_text2,game_over_rect2)
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(5)

                break

        point_text = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 36).render("SCORE" + str(point), 1, (255, 0, 0))
        point_rect = point_text.get_rect(center=(450,450))
        sc.blit(point_text, point_rect)
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.Clock().tick(FPS)

    time.sleep(1)

    while hard:

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                hard = False

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and hero.rect[0]  < SCREEN[0]:

            hero.update_hero('RIGHT')

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and hero.rect[0] > 0:

            hero.update_hero('LEFT')

        update()
        pygame.display.update()

        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(floor,object_group):

            object1.kill()
            object2.kill()
            object3.kill()
            object4.kill()
            object5.kill()
            object6.kill()
            object7.kill()

            object1 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
            object2 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
            object3 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
            object4 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
            object5 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
            object6 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)
            object7 = Object.box(picture[randint(0,3)], object_group, y_object_1)

            point+=1

        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(hero,object_group):

            life_count-=1

            if life_count == 0:

                object1.kill()
                object2.kill()
                object3.kill()
                object4.kill()
                object5.kill()
                object6.kill()
                object7.kill()

                sc.fill(BLUE)
                heart1.kill()

                game_over_text = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 36).render("GAME OVER" , 1, (255, 0, 0))
                game_over_text2 = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 36).render( "SCORE: " + str(point) , 1, (255, 0, 0))

                game_over_rect = game_over_text.get_rect(center=(SCREEN[0]//2, SCREEN[1]//2))
                game_over_rect2 = game_over_text.get_rect(center=(SCREEN[0]//2, (SCREEN[1]//2)+50))

                sc.blit(game_over_text,game_over_rect)
                sc.blit(game_over_text2,game_over_rect2)
                pygame.display.update()
                time.sleep(5)

                break

        point_text = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 36).render("SCORE" + str(point), 1, (255, 0, 0))
        point_rect = point_text.get_rect(center=(450,450))
        sc.blit(point_text, point_rect)
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.Clock().tick(FPS)
```

Comment: The question needs a description of what the code does. It is very difficult to write a good code review when we don't know what the code is supposed to do, and don't know what the expected output is.

Answer (score 6):

There's too much code here to be able to quickly review it to find your performance bottlenecks.  I'd recommend running it under a performance profiler to see which specific functions your program spends the most time executing so you can focus your optimization on those functions:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html

This did jump out at me, though:

```
time.sleep(0.001)
```

because it's executed in the `update` function of each individual object, and since this program is single-threaded, everything else is going to be paused while that sleep is happening, so the more objects you have in the game, the slower each update cycle will be.  If you have a hundred objects, it'll take a tenth of a second to update them all, and if your screen refresh is blocked on that, that means you're getting at best 10fps.

What you probably want to do is have a single timer that triggers an update on all the objects.